# How to loop through a dynamically loaded asp.net menu control and remove some items?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net C# webforms project. On the master page I have a menu control which I populate dynamically in the page load event of the master page. When a page is accessed, I want to loop through the items in the menu, and redirect the user to login page if the url is not present in the menu. I am doing this in the page_Load event of the custom base page class which the content pages derive from. The problem I am having is that the Items count of the menu comes as zero. The following is my code:

```
    <asp:Menu ID="menuBarMaster" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"   Width="100%"  
            CssClass="MenuBarMaster" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="10"   ClientIDMode="Static">               
            <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="staticMenuItem" />   
            <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="staticHoverStyle"></StaticHoverStyle>             
            <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="staticMenuItemStyle" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="staticSelectedStyle" />              
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="dynamicMenuItemStyle" />
            <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="dynamicHoverStyle" />
            <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="dynamicMenuStyle" />
        </asp:Menu>

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        var menu = this.Master.FindControl("menuBarMaster") as Menu;
        if (menu != null)
        {
            if (menu.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                //loop through the items
        //But this is never reached as the menu.Items.Count equals to 0
            }
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are facing the problem because MasterPage's OnLoad event handler is called after Content Page's OnLoad event handler.

See this: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/asp-net-page-events-lifecycle